# Great ID-Ten-T Errors

Tags: user

Working at a help desk for a school I've gotten to see some rather classic Tech Support problems:

> Prof: The projector isn't working.
>
> My self: Is the computer turned on?
>
> Prof: Hey! It works now. Thanks

Or

> Student: My laptop doesn't have any wireless, fix it!
>
> My self: See this little button on the middle of your computer that looks like a radio tower?
>
> Student: Yea
>
> My self: ok, see how its orange, that means wireless is off. you press it, then it turns blue and wireless is turned on.

and I could go on like that. But I'm very certain I'm not the only one who has had these moments. So what are some of the greatest [ID10T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-Ten-T_Error) errors that you've had to solve?

Comment: Recommendation to close this question. According to the FAQ: **Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!**

Comment: BTW, just making something community wiki does not excuse it from being closed.

Comment: Without arguing with the upper two, I just wanna say, I love it :) One question doesn't strain my bandwidth that much, and this has the potential to turn into one of "the great ones".

Comment: I thought so to. But as usual the mods and I don't see eye to eye. xD I've seen a lot of questions on SU(and even on SO) that are like the one I've posted here, and they aren't closed. Some how I always interpret that line in the FAQ differently from (names listed below). *srug* it was worth a shot. Though I would like to point out that this question is not subjective, is not argumentative, and does not require extended discussion. and questions like these are good for the community, it gives experienced IT and novice IT common grounds to laugh about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UserFriendly.org](http://ars.userfriendly.org/cartoons/?id=19980219&mode=classic) ... Greg pretty much heard them all :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

PICNIC

Problem In Chair Not In Computer

Comment: Isn't that PEBKAC ? - Problem Exists Between Keyboard And Chair ;-)